# Spray hose connector for delta kitchen faucet?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

The connection from the spray hose to my kitchen faucet was made out of the cheapest of plastic and started leaking. I purchased a ["universal" spray hose replacement](https://www.danco.com/product/universal-premium-sink-side-spray-replacement-hose/) at the local hardware store. In the course of removing the old hose, all the brittle plastic tabs snapped and I'm left with the a brass connector on the pipe into the faucet that has two small o-rings and then a couple small grooves.

Unfortunately, none of the connectors included in the kit seem to match up. What are my options?

Edit: the original connector looked like the one pictured in this video:  https://youtu.be/BpvqiO7iLk4

However, mine completely disintegrated when trying to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is a specialty assembly specific to that brand of faucet. You will need to either find a plumbing shop that has exact replacement parts (as opposed to some "universal" assembly; which actually isn't, obviously) or source the parts from Delta as the person in your linked video did.